# Service not fully stopped after ServiceController.Stop()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, service

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(someService);
serviceController.Stop();
serviceController.WaitForStopped();
DoSomething();
```

SomeService works on a sqlserver file. DoSomething() wants to copy that SQL file. If SomeService isn't closed fully it will throw an error because the database file is still locked. In the aforementioned code, I get past the WaitForStopped() method and yet the service doesn't release the database file until after DoSomething(), thus I get an error.

Doing some more investigation, I find that before the DoSomething method call I see that the service controller status shows a stopped and yet looking at some ProcMon logs the service releases the database file after I'm thrown an error from DoSomething.

Also, if I put a Thread.Sleep between the WaitForStopped and the DoSomething method for say... 5 seconds, the database file is released and all is well. Not the solution of surety I'm looking for however.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceController.WaitForStopped()/WaitForStatus() will return once the service implementation claims it has stopped.  This doesn't necessary mean the process has released all of its resources and has exited.  I've seen database other than SQL Server do this as well.

If you really want to be sure the database is fully and truly stopped, you will have to interface with the database itself, get ahold of the process id and wait for it to exit, wait for locks on the files to be released, ...

Comment: Hrm, this answers why. Any ideas on a good workaround though?

Answer (score 22):

Windows Services are a layer on top of processes; in order to be a service, an application must connect to the Service Control Manager and announce which services are available. This connection is handled within the ADVAPI32.DLL library. Once this connection is established, the library maintains a thread waiting for commands from the Service Control Manager, which can then start and stop services arbitrarily. I don't believe the process is required to exit when the last service in it terminates. Though that is what typically happens, the end of the link with the Service Control Manager, which occurs after the last service enters the "Stopped" state, can occur significantly before the process actually terminates, releasing any resources it hasn't already explicitly released.

The Windows Service API includes functionality that lets you obtain the Process ID of the process that is hosting the service. It is possible for a single process to host many services, and so the process might not actually exit when the service you are interested in has terminated, but you should be safe with SQL Server. Unfortunately, the .NET Framework does not expose this functionality. It does, however, expose the handle to the service that it uses internally for API calls, and you can use it to make your own API calls. With a bit of P/Invoke, then, you can obtain the process ID of the Windows Service process, and from there, provided you have the necessary permission, you can open a handle to the process that can be used to wait for it to exit.

Something like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32")]
static extern bool QueryServiceStatusEx(IntPtr hService, int InfoLevel, ref SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS lpBuffer, int cbBufSize, out int pcbBytesNeeded);

const int SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO = 0;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS
{
  public int dwServiceType;
  public int dwCurrentState;
  public int dwControlsAccepted;
  public int dwWin32ExitCode;
  public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
  public int dwCheckPoint;
  public int dwWaitHint;
  public int dwProcessId;
  public int dwServiceFlags;
}

const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;
const int SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000100;

const int SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS = 0x00000001;

public static void StopServiceAndWaitForExit(string serviceName)
{
  using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName))
  {
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp = new SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS();
    int ignored;

    // Obtain information about the service, and specifically its hosting process,
    // from the Service Control Manager.
    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(controller.ServiceHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, ref ssp, Marshal.SizeOf(ssp), out ignored))
      throw new Exception("Couldn't obtain service process information.");

    // A few quick sanity checks that what the caller wants is *possible*.
    if ((ssp.dwServiceType & ~SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS) != SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS)
      throw new Exception("Can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because there may be multiple services in the process (dwServiceType is not SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS");

    if ((ssp.dwServiceFlags & SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS) != 0)
      throw new Exception("Can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because the hosting process is a critical system process that will not exit (SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS flag set)");

    if (ssp.dwProcessId == 0)
      throw new Exception("Can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because the process ID is not known.");

    // Note: It is possible for the next line to throw an ArgumentException if the
    // Service Control Manager's information is out-of-date (e.g. due to the process
    // having *just* been terminated in Task Manager) and the process does not really
    // exist. This is a race condition. The exception is the desirable result in this
    // case.
    using (Process process = Process.GetProcessById(ssp.dwProcessId))
    {
      // EDIT: There is no need for waiting in a separate thread, because MSDN says "The handles are valid until closed, even after the process or thread they represent has been terminated." ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ), so to keep things in the same thread, the process HANDLE should be opened from the process id before the service is stopped, and the Wait should be done after that.

      // Response to EDIT: What you report is true, but the problem is that the handle isn't actually opened by Process.GetProcessById. It's only opened within the .WaitForExit method, which won't return until the wait is complete. Thus, if we try the wait on the current therad, we can't actually do anything until it's done, and if we defer the check until after the process has completed, it won't be possible to obtain a handle to it any more.

      // The actual wait, using process.WaitForExit, opens a handle with the SYNCHRONIZE
      // permission only and closes the handle before returning. As long as that handle
      // is open, the process can be monitored for termination, but if the process exits
      // before the handle is opened, it is no longer possible to open a handle to the
      // original process and, worse, though it exists only as a technicality, there is
      // a race condition in that another process could pop up with the same process ID.
      // As such, we definitely want the handle to be opened before we ask the service
      // to close, but since the handle's lifetime is only that of the call to WaitForExit
      // and while WaitForExit is blocking the thread we can't make calls into the SCM,
      // it would appear to be necessary to perform the wait on a separate thread.
      ProcessWaitForExitData threadData = new ProcessWaitForExitData();

      threadData.Process = process;

      Thread processWaitForExitThread = new Thread(ProcessWaitForExitThreadProc);

      processWaitForExitThread.IsBackground = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground;
      processWaitForExitThread.Start(threadData);

      // Now we ask the service to exit.
      controller.Stop();

      // Instead of waiting until the *service* is in the "stopped" state, here we
      // wait for its hosting process to go away. Of course, it's really that other
      // thread waiting for the process to go away, and then we wait for the thread
      // to go away.
      lock (threadData.Sync)
        while (!threadData.HasExited)
          Monitor.Wait(threadData.Sync);
    }
  }
}

class ProcessWaitForExitData
{
  public Process Process;
  public volatile bool HasExited;
  public object Sync = new object();
}

static void ProcessWaitForExitThreadProc(object state)
{
  ProcessWaitForExitData threadData = (ProcessWaitForExitData)state;

  try
  {
    threadData.Process.WaitForExit();
  }
  catch {}
  finally
  {
    lock (threadData.Sync)
    {
      threadData.HasExited = true;
      Monitor.PulseAll(threadData.Sync);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `ssp.dwServiceType` needs to be evaluated as a flags – may also contain **SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS** (0x100) flag

Comment: I have made an edit to check for this, thanks. :-)

Comment: Excellent Thanks ! I would ditch `HasExited` and the `Sync` lock and use `AutoResetEvent` instead .. also would be cool to add a timeout

Comment: also, you say you need to call `WaitForExit` before stopping the service so we do it in a separate thread, but what guarantees the  `WaitForExit` in the thread happens first ? not easy to solve .. add a sleep ?

Comment: It's technically possible, yes, that the service could shut down and exit before the thread starts, and then another process could start and get the same process ID, causing it to wait on a completely unrelated process. But it's exceedingly unlikely; the process of stopping a service generally takes orders of magnitude longer than starting a thread.  To properly close this gap, you'd need to ensure that you had an open handle to the process _before_ asking the service to stop. Then, a separate thread wouldn't be needed any more; the handle remains valid even if the process has exited.

Comment: But, C# doesn't provide a way to do that, as far as I know, so you'd have to resort to P/Invoke-ing the underlying API.

Comment: To clarify, if you access the `Handle` property, it will open and persist a handle to the process that can be used for waiting. But, that handle requests `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, which is way more than we need and which means that, typically, user code waiting for a _service_ to exit won't have permission.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have used the interops:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SC_HANDLE__
{
    public int unused;
}

[Flags]
public enum SERVICE_CONTROL : uint
{
    STOP = 0x00000001,
    PAUSE = 0x00000002,
    CONTINUE = 0x00000003,
    INTERROGATE = 0x00000004,
    SHUTDOWN = 0x00000005,
    PARAMCHANGE = 0x00000006,
    NETBINDADD = 0x00000007,
    NETBINDREMOVE = 0x00000008,
    NETBINDENABLE = 0x00000009,
    NETBINDDISABLE = 0x0000000A,
    DEVICEEVENT = 0x0000000B,
    HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE = 0x0000000C,
    POWEREVENT = 0x0000000D,
    SESSIONCHANGE = 0x0000000E
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SERVICE_STATUS
{

    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwServiceType;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwCurrentState;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwControlsAccepted;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwWin32ExitCode;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwCheckPoint;
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwWaitHint;
}

public class NativeMethods
{
    public const int SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
                | (SC_MANAGER_CONNECT
                | (SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE
                | (SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE
                | (SC_MANAGER_LOCK
                | (SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG))))));

    /// STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED -> (0x000F0000L)
    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 983040;
    /// SC_MANAGER_CONNECT -> 0x0001
    public const int SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 1;
    /// SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE -> 0x0002
    public const int SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 2;
    /// SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE -> 0x0004
    public const int SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 4;
    /// SC_MANAGER_LOCK -> 0x0008
    public const int SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 8;
    /// SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS -> 0x0010
    public const int SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 16;
    /// SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG -> 0x0020
    public const int SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 32;
    /// SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP -> 0x00000001
    public const int SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP = 1;
    /// SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS -> 0x0004
    public const int SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 4;
    public const int GENERIC_EXECUTE = 536870912;
    /// SERVICE_RUNNING -> 0x00000004
    public const int SERVICE_RUNNING = 4;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManagerW(
        [In()] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpMachineName,
        [In()] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpDatabaseName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ControlService(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONTROL dwControl, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "QueryServiceStatus", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, ref SERVICE_STATUS dwServiceStatus);

    [SecurityCritical]
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public static void ServiceStop()
    {
        IntPtr manager = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr service = IntPtr.Zero;
        SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

        if ((manager = OpenSCManagerW(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)) != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if ((service = OpenService(manager, Resources.ServiceName, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)) != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                QueryServiceStatus(service, ref status);
            }

            if (status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
            {
                int i = 0;
                //not the best way, but WaitStatus didnt work correctly. 
                while (i++ < 10 && status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
                {
                    ControlService(service, SERVICE_CONTROL.STOP, ref status);
                    QueryServiceStatus(service, ref status);
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }

            }
        }


        if (manager != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var b = CloseServiceHandle(manager);
        }

        if (service != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var b = CloseServiceHandle(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help? The service could still REPORT stopped while not terminating (immediately). It can take a 'wee bit of time' (up to 2 seconds) for a .NET App Domain to shutdown - especially if there is alot going on in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when I stopped a service that was a dependency to another service, and the second service was holding resources I didn't even know it was using. Do you think this might be the case? I know SQL has quite a few different components, but I haven't looked into whether there are multiple services associated with it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even using @Jonathan Gilbert excellent answer I still had cases where I could not delete the service executable file after the service process was stopped. I found out I had to also call `process.Kill()` at the end of it all to totally free resources.

Here is a version of Jonathan Gilbert answer which adds `Kill`, a timeout, and better thread synchronization:

```
namespace System.ServiceProcess {
  public static class ExtensionMethods {
    [DllImport("advapi32")]
    static extern bool QueryServiceStatusEx(IntPtr hService, int InfoLevel, ref SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS lpBuffer, int cbBufSize, out int pcbBytesNeeded);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] struct SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS { public int dwServiceType; public int dwCurrentState; public int dwControlsAccepted; public int dwWin32ExitCode; public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode; public int dwCheckPoint; public int dwWaitHint; public int dwProcessId; public int dwServiceFlags; }
    const int SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO = 0, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010, SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000100, SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS = 0x00000001;

    record ProcessWaitForExitData(int ProcessId, AutoResetEvent MWaitForThread, int TimeoutMilliseconds);

    // wait for the actual process that runs the service to stop
    public static void StopAndWaitForProcessToExit(this ServiceController controller, int timeoutMilliseconds=-1) {
      var processId = -1;

      try {
        var ssp = new SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS();
        // check can't obtain service process informatio
        if (QueryServiceStatusEx(controller.ServiceHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, ref ssp, Marshal.SizeOf(ssp), out int ignored)
        // check can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because there may be multiple services in the process (dwServiceType is not SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS)
        && (ssp.dwServiceType & ~SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS) == SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        // check can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because the hosting process is a critical system process that will not exit (SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS flag set)");
        && (ssp.dwServiceFlags & SERVICE_RUNS_IN_SYSTEM_PROCESS) == 0
        // chec can't wait for the service's hosting process to exit because the process ID is not known.");
        && ssp.dwProcessId != 0) processId = ssp.dwProcessId;
      } catch (Exception) {
      }

      if (processId==-1) {
        controller.Stop(); // stop the service
        return; // we did all we can
      }

      // we need to call WaitForExit before stopping the service so we do it in a separate thread 
      var mWaitForThread = new AutoResetEvent(false);
      var processWaitForExitThread = new Thread(ProcessWaitForExitThreadProc) { IsBackground = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground };
      processWaitForExitThread.Start(new ProcessWaitForExitData(processId, mWaitForThread, timeoutMilliseconds));
      Task.Delay(5).Wait(); // let thread reach WaitForExit, is there a better way ?

      controller.Stop(); // stop the service
      mWaitForThread.WaitOne(); // wait for process to exit
    }

    static void ProcessWaitForExitThreadProc(object? state) {
      ProcessWaitForExitData threadData = (ProcessWaitForExitData)state!;
      try {
        using Process process = Process.GetProcessById(threadData.ProcessId);
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        process.WaitForExit(threadData.TimeoutMilliseconds);
        process.Kill(true); // free all process resources
        var killTimeout = threadData.TimeoutMilliseconds==-1 ? -1 : (int)Math.Max(threadData.TimeoutMilliseconds - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, 10);
        if (!process.WaitForExit(killTimeout)) throw new TimeoutException();
      }
      catch { }
      finally {
        threadData.MWaitForThread.Set();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To use:

```
using ServiceController controller = new(serviceName);
controller.StopAndWaitForProcessToExit(timeoutMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score -5):

Try to use Environment.Exit(1);

Comment: Forcibly terminating SQL Server is a very bad idea.