# Make windows service REALLY stop

Tags: c#, windows-services

A WCF service is hosted in a windows service. For smoother development, the service is stopped by `net stop [Service]` in a pre-build task and then unistalled, installed and started in a post-build task.

**Problem**:

`net stop [Service]` doesn't wait till the process is fully terminated and all the resources are released. This behavior is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884853/service-not-fully-stopped-after-servicecontroller-stop) for example. As a result, when the service is compiled, the binaries in the bin directory (that's where the service lives) are still locked and can't be overwritten with the new copies.

Is there an easy way to make the pre-build `net stop` wait until the resources are released, and return only then? I could grab the process ID and wait for it to terminate, but it seems a bit heavy handed for such a simple task.

Comment: I use Jonathan Gilbert's solution that you have already linked to. It works perfectly, and in my opinion it is the "cleanest" method.

Comment: A service implements a logical stop.  Nothing you couldn't hurry along with task manager or taskkill.exe if necessary.